# htaccess rewrite needs one exception

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble defining an exception for a single URL on a site that needs to all be https except one subdirectory.

I currently have:

```
## Redirect URLs to https://
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

But I need to define an exception around www.example.com/forum so that it's always http://www.example.com/forum, without the https:// protocol.

How can I do this? I've tried all kinds of ! operators on RewriteCond, but the %SERVER_PORT seems to take precedence. Is there another RewriteCond I should consider?

Answer (score 1):

Replace last line :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

With this :

```
RewriteRule !^/?forum  https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

If it is Ok , replace `[R,L]` with `[R=301,L]` to be permanent redirection

**Update**

As per your comment that you want to force any `https` request contains `forum` into `http` you could add these rules along with rules above :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !80
RewriteRule ^/?forum  http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work fine when the URL is typed in directly, staying at http and not redirecting to https. But whenever a relative link to ```<a href="/forum">``` anywhere on the website that hosts the forum is clicked, it wants to go to https rather than http. Even with the exception defined in the RewriteRule. Is there a way to force it even more? The CMS only points to relative URLs and won't let me define absolute with http.

Comment: @rw-intechra you could add new rules opposite way , I will update answer just wait

Comment: Thanks. I added those lines and refreshed the browser several times, but it still wants to go to https for the forum. This was just meant as a temporary fix until the forum could be made secure, so I guess I just need to make the forum secure right away.

Comment: Clearing browser cache didn't work either. Thanks for helping me, though. I learned something new.